# bone axis-orientation is unexpected changed when modify bone.tail by python

Tags: python, armature, bones

I want straighten editbone, but using python
`bone.tail = bone.head + bone.parent.y_axis*bone.length`
will unexpected change axis-orientation.
How should I fix it?
[image: start]

[image: python]

[image: result]

Comment: I had [a similar problem](https://developer.blender.org/T88581). Try using Blender 3.0 if you aren't already, it may be fixed.

Comment: @scurest  Is it ? i download blender 3.0.zip , it still is wrong.